# Are glasses muktzeh on shabbat for Jews who can see

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, see-sight-vision-blind, orach-chaim

According to the Halacha, are glasses muktzeh   on Shabbat for Jews who can see fine without them? Or no, are they not muktzeh and may they be moved on Shabbat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [S"A Harav, 318:41](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3775912/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-308-Articles-that-Are-Permitted-and-Prohibited-to-Be-Moved-on-Shabbos.htm#v41) where he states that the status of muktzeh is a status that is dependent on the object and its owner, and that status propagates to all people who dwell in his home, regardless of whether the condition which would render the item muktzeh applies to them or not.

If the item has been discarded, or is otherwise being used by someone who is not staying in his home, then their personal rules apply. In that halacha, that would mean that a rich person could not consider rags to be clothes and hence they are muktzeh, while a poor person may consider them to be clothes.